# How to improve English quality of my paper?

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style

I am in phase of writing 2nd paper. Previous paper is rejected. The one of the main objection in previous paper was English quality. As English is not my native language and reviewers only say "there are some mistakes, paper quality needs to be improved". This puts me doubt in myself and my major concern becomes writing instead of doing research. I spend a lot of time to read my paper again and again and re-write sentences. But how do I know that it is good now. It is infinite loop for me. What should I do to enhance quality of English. I have nobody available to review my paper for me. Kindly give me some suggestions:

- What about online proofreading software i.e. grammarly, language tool, perfectit etc? which one do you use especially for scientific writing form computer science domain?
- What about online copy-editors and proofreaders that are available to read my paper. I have checked some websites but the charges were too high. Do you have used any service like this that had affordable cost
- any other options?

Comment: Duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/149768/64